# I am trying to run command aplay and arecord and it does not work also pulseaudio is having some issues

Tags: pulseaudio, pyalsaaudio

I am trying to run commands like aplay, arecord but I get following error

```
ALSA lib ../../alsa-plugins-1.2.1/pulse/pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Timeout
arecord: main:828: audio open error: Connection refused
```

When I tried to start the pulse audio using command: pulseaudio I get following errors:

```
[pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.  
[pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="platform-soc_qcom_msm-audio-apr_qcom_q6core-audio_sound-adp-star" card_name="alsa_card.platform-soc_qcom_msm-audio-apr_qcom_q6core-audio_sound-adp-star" namereg_fail=false tsched=no fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=no avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
```

And command pacmd give following output:

```
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

And if try to run arecord with plughw I get this error:

```
arecord -D plughw:0,1 audio.wav  
Recording WAVE 'audio.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono   
**arecord: set_params:1405: Unable to install hw params:**  
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED  
FORMAT:  U8  
SUBFORMAT:  STD  
SAMPLE_BITS: 8  
FRAME_BITS: 8  
CHANNELS: 1  
RATE: 8000  
PERIOD_TIME: 126000  
PERIOD_SIZE: 1008   
PERIOD_BYTES: 1008  
PERIODS: 4  
BUFFER_TIME: 504000  
BUFFER_SIZE: 4032  
BUFFER_BYTES: 4032  
TICK_TIME: 0
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my device, can someone please help?

Comment: Which devices are visible for arecord; what is the output of 'arecord -l'

Comment: Recording with 'arecord -D plughw:1,0 -d 5 audio.wav' works for me. I added '-d 5' to make the recording terminate after 5 seconds. 1,0 I picked from the listing produced by 'arecord -l':

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
...
card 1: GoMic [Samson GoMic], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0